# Epson EH-TW6800 projector in ubuntu

Tags: projector

I am new to Ubuntu and trying to connect an Epson EH-TW6800 Projector via USB. Nothing is happening. 
How do I get started from the beginning?

I am using:

- Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
- processor: Intel® Core™ i7-4700MQ CPU @ 2.40GHz × 8
- Graphics : Intel® Haswell Mobile
- OS type : 64-bit
- Projector: Epson EH-TW6800

Output of `lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0bda:571a Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:07da Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 028: ID 04b8:061b Seiko Epson Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 027: ID 04b8:0907 Seiko Epson Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 026: ID 0bb4:0c02 HTC (High Tech Computer Corp.) Dream   / ADP1 / G1 / Magic / Tattoo (Debug)
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 138a:0050 Validity Sensors, Inc. Swipe           Fingerprint Sensor
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

On the Detect Display Mirror output its not detecting anything. I have tried to low resolution to 800x600 still not showing.

Comment: Please add details about the hardware/model etc and the output of `lsusb` after connecting the device to your question.

Comment: I have added the Isusb output

Comment: What about the model of projector?

Comment: On the Detect Display Mirror output its not detecting anything. I have tried to low resolution to 800x600 still not showing.

Comment: The Model is EPSON

Comment: @user3671937: Epson is most likely the brand - not the model :)

Comment: the model is EH-TW6800 :)

Answer (score 1):

**Epson EH-TW6800** admits HDMI (2x) and VGA video inputs. Additionally it supports network with an Ethernet port or WLAN (optional).

It has an integrated media player for local media via an USB2.0 type A port or network via the aforementioned network connections.

**The additional USB2.0 type B port is for service only.**

You are not supposed to connect it via USB. The type A port is for USB flash drives and the type B one is for firmware update and diagnostics.
Please connect it to your Ubuntu computer using HDMI (preferable) or VGA (D-SUB). Adjust the settings the same way you would do with an additional monitor.